# noImplicitAny:true 設定時のobjectのアクセスについて教えて下さい

Tags: typescript

`"noImplicitAny": true`の設定で以下のコードを書いています

```
    let tables = [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
    ];

    let select_columns = {
        'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
        'b': ['b1', 'b2'],
        'c': ['c1', 'c2']
    };
    for (let table of tables) {
        console.log(select_columns[table]);
    }
```

するとconcole.logの箇所で以下の様なエラーが出てしまいます。

```
[ts] 
Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
let select_columns: {
    'a': string[];
    'b': string[];
    'c': string[];
}
```

エラーが出ないようにするにはどの様に書けばいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように型注釈を書きましょう。

```
let select_columns: {[idx: string]: string[]} = {
    ...
}

// または

interface Columns {
    [idx: string]: string[];
}

let select_columns: Columns = {
    ...
}
```

idxは任意の識別子で構いません。

この型は、string型で[]アクセスするとstring[]型を返すようなオブジェクトを表します。
この型注釈を書かないと、select_columnsは3つのメンバーa、b、cを持つオブジェクトと解釈されます。
その場合、例えば`select_columns['a']`はコンパイルエラーになりません。